# Disable click after 5 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

After I click 5 times on `table:eq(0) td`  I want to disable the first function and after i click 2 times on `table.dvojka td` I want to disable the second function.

```
$("table:eq(0) td").click(function () {
$(this).addClass("tdbarva");
});

$("table.dvojka td").click(function () {
$(this).addClass("barvica");

});
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to disable the button?

Comment: I'm guessing it isn't so much disable the button as remove the click handling event listener. But you're right, where does that event listening removal bit happen?

Answer (score 2):

You'd first need to create at least two global counters that keeps track of the clicks. Then in each click event handler you'd have to check if the clicks match your threshold. From there you use **[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** to remove the event handlers from each `<td/>`.

```js
let clickCountOne = 0;
let clickCountTwo = 0;

$("table:eq(0) td").click(function() {
  clickCountOne++;

  if (clickCountOne === 5) {
    console.log('Click handler has been disabled for first table td');

    $(this).off('click');
  }

  $(this).addClass("tdbarva");
});

$("table.dvojka td").click(function() {
  clickCountTwo++;

  if (clickCountTwo === 2) {
    console.log('Click handler has been disabled for second table td');
    
    $(this).off('click');
  }

  $(this).addClass("barvica");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>Click Me</td>
</table>

<table class="dvojka">
  <td>Click Me Too</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using a data attribute on the table itself to keep count of clicks. When either table is clicked, its count attribute is updated. Then its event listener is called, which compares that dynamic count against a static limiter (manually typed into the DOM node). If the count exceeds the limit, i use the jQuery off() function to remove that table's event handler.

Hope this helps!

```js
// Set my click counter to zero for all tables...
$("table").each(function() {
  $(this).data("clickCount", 0);
});

// Create the references to each table element.
var firstTable = $("table:eq(0)");
var secondTable = $("table.dvojka");

// Attach my event listeners...
firstTable.on("click", "td", firstFunc);
secondTable.on("click", "td", secondFunc);

/****
 * Each table will maintain its own click count data attribute.
 *
 ****/
$("table td").on("click", function() {
  var clickedTable = $(this).parents("table");
  var clickCount = parseInt(clickedTable.data("clickCount")) + 1;
  var clickLimit = clickedTable.attr("data-clickLimiter");

    clickedTable.data("clickCount", clickCount);
});

/*****
 * The following functions are used in the event listeners for the
 *  tables, and are tracking their own count to determine when to
 *  disable themselves.
 *****/
function firstFunc(evt){
  // the clickCount is dynamic, created by the program itself.
  //  The clickLimiter is a static attribute, defined on the DOM node manually.
  var clickCount = parseInt(firstTable.data("clickCount"));
  var clickLimit = parseInt(firstTable.attr("data-clickLimiter") );
  
  // Has the count exceeded our limit?
  if(clickCount >= clickLimit){
    // If it has, remove the event listener.
    firstTable.off("click", "td", firstFunc);
  }
  console.log("You've clicked the first table "+
              clickCount + 
              " times. It has a limit of " +
              clickLimit +
              " clicks, or " +
              parseInt(clickLimit-clickCount) +
              " remaining");
}

function secondFunc(){
  var clickCount = parseInt(secondTable.data("clickCount"));
  var clickLimit = parseInt(secondTable.attr("data-clickLimiter") );
  
  if(clickCount >= clickLimit){
    secondTable.off("click", "td", secondFunc);
  }
  console.log("You've clicked the second table "+
              clickCount + 
              " times. It has a limit of " +
              clickLimit +
              " clicks, or " +
              parseInt(clickLimit-clickCount) +
              " remaining");
}
```

```css
.dvojka {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-clickLimiter=5>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>baz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01-01</td>
      <td>01-02</td>
      <td>01-03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02-01</td>
      <td>02-02</td>
      <td>02-03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03-01</td>
      <td>03-02</td>
      <td>03-03</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="dvojka" data-clickLimiter=2>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>baz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01-01</td>
      <td>01-02</td>
      <td>01-03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02-01</td>
      <td>02-02</td>
      <td>02-03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03-01</td>
      <td>03-02</td>
      <td>03-03</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that this could just as easily have been done with a single click handler for both tables, and it would only disable for the appropriate table -- but I can only assume that the processing for both tables would somehow be different. If both tables have the exact same click functionality, then it would be a trivial matter to remove the second table's click handler, and simply have the one function for all tables.